# How to fix this End of Expression error in the markup of my Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

> Error: $parse:ueoe
>   Unexpected End of Expression

Looking at Chrome, this is what I see in the console:
`<div ng-class="{" green-up":="" tgh.tag.direction="=" "positive",="" "red-down":="" "negative",="" ""="" :="" "stagnant"}"="">`

[image]

Here is a link to [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/leongaban/14d5dd109e8c58322fe0) for an easier read.

```
template : 
    '<div class="tags-hover-container" ng-show="tgh.tag.tagsHoverDisplay"> ' +
        '<div class="tag-info-padding"> ' +
            '<div class="tweets-direction" ng-hide="!tgh.tag.quantity"> ' +
                '<div ng-hide="tgh.tag.length"> ' +
                    '<div ng-class="{"green-up": tgh.tag.direction == "positive", ' +
                                    '"red-down": tgh.tag.direction == "negative", ' +
                                    '""        : tgh.tag.direction == "stagnant"}"> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '<div class="tweet-percentage">{{tgh.tag.tweet_percentage}}%</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '<div class="tweet-count">{{tgh.tag.quantity}} tweets</div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '<div class="tweets-direction" ng-show="!tgh.tag.quantity">0 tweets</div> ' +
            '<div class="associated-tags"> ' +
                '<ul> ' +
                    '<li ng-repeat="ticker in tgh.tag.tickers"> ' +
                        '<div class="ticker" ng-click="tgh.selectTicker(ticker)">{{ticker}}</div> ' +
                    '</li> ' +
                '</ul> ' +
            '</div> ' +
        '</div> ' +
        '<div class="trending-tags-container"> ' +
            '<div class="trending-tags" title="trending tags"> ' +
                '<ul><li ng-repeat="trend in tgh.tag.momentum_twitter_preview">{{trend}}</li></ul> ' +
            '</div> ' +
        '</div> ' +
        '<div class="tag-actions"> ' +
            '<div class="tag-action-padding"> ' +
                '<div class="hide-tag" title="Coming soon"> ' +
                    '<div class="close-x-sml"></div>Hide Tag ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '<div class="add-my-watchlist" ' +
                     'ng-hide="tgh.tag.favorite == 1 || faved" ' +
                     'ng-click="tgh.addFavorite(tag)" title="Add to Favorites"> ' +
                     '+ My Favorites ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '<div class="add-my-watchlist" ' +
                     'ng-show="tgh.tag.favorite == 1 || faved" ' +
                     'ng-click="tgh.removeFavorite(tag)" title="Remove from Favorites"> ' +
                     '- My Favorites ' +
                '</div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
        '</div> ' +
        '<div class="tags-hover-bg"></div> ' +
    '</div>',
restrict: "E",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid markup here:

```
<div ng-class="{"green-up": tgh.tag.direction == "positive", ' + ...
```

You should escape the double quotes inside double quotes with `\` or use single quotes.

Comment: Ok, how would I fix that in the context above? I have to use the single quote because I break the lines so the template markup is easily viewable.  `'+'`

Comment: Yup, you can encode to make valid markup. Any reason you are using `template` instead of `templateUrl`? Seperate html would really help for readability.

Comment: Yeah I originally had it outside of, but it seems to function a bit quicker... by milisecs. Not just that, but I'm trying to cut down on requests. So right now with dev scripts I have over 80 files getting downloaded, with all my Angular modules concatenated it goes down to 50 something, if I move all my template HTML files into the Directives, I cut out another 20+! Yeah some trade offs...

Comment: Have you tried [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for production build? We have a build task that compiles all the html into js template via `grunt-html2js` and concat, uglify by `grunt-contrib-concat` and `grunt-contrib-uglify`.

Comment: We're using Gulp, but hmm wondering how would that work... would you have to change up something in the Directives as well? To point to something in the js template? I'll checkout what Gulp has...